# Build fails every time with "Error: Process completed with exit code 2."

Tags: java, maven, github-actions

I wrote the GitHub action workflow and it failed with error code 2.
I want to run a java program when the GitHub action is executed.

GitHub actions workflow:

```yaml
name: CI

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - run: javac /Users/user-name/git/repository/my-first-framework/src/main/java/InterviewPrep/StringReverse.java
```

Comment: Is that your complete workflow? There must be more logs before this error specifying the actual problem. Please add those in your question as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.